# How to set up predicates in KRL?

Tags: krl

I have the following in my global block:

```
test = defaction(){
    if(5>10) then {
        notify("yes","yes");    
    }
}
```

Then I also have the following rule:

```
rule tester {
    select when pageview ".*"
    test();
}
```

I am expecting that the notify will never happen, as 5 will never be greater than 10. However, it runs on every single page. I am sure that I am doing it wrong, although it feels right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates (such as `if (5>10) then` are not part of the action block. As such, including predicatees in a `defaction` doesn't make sense. You'll have to write it more like this:

```
global {
    test = defaction(){
        notify("yes","yes");    
    }
}

rule tester {
    select when pageview ".*" setting ()
    if (5>10) then {
        test();
    }
}
```

The `if...then` construct fulfills the same function as, say, the `every` construct: it wraps the action block.

Comment: You are correct. Conditions must be placed outside a defaction. If you want neat features allowing either/or action behavior, bug @pjw about 'Non-random Choose'.